# Разделитель для данных в БД MySQL

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Какой разделитель лучше всего и почему?

Задача: записывать данные в БД, в один столбец, в одну строчку, через разделитель. Тип данных - числовой.

Сейчас такой вариант думаю использовать: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Т.е. в качестве разделителя - запятая. Возможно, есть альтернативный разделитель, который лучше?

Comment: зачем? как ты их будешь юзать? нечего непонятно с вопроса.

Comment: у нас есть цифры. цифры необходимо разделять. как лучше всего их разделять (с помощью какого символа)?
т.е. эти данные хранятся в БД.


как буду юзать - поиск по этим данным буду делать (сначала запись, потом поиск).

Comment: Вполне нормальный разделитель. Все обычно используют запятую, в качестве разделителя.

Comment: в моем понимании все символы занимают разное количество байт. Так вот, есть ли символ, занимающий меньше байт, чем запятая?

Comment: может структуру нада переделать? нормализацию провести чтоб потом не было больно от запрсов и скорости их выполнения?

Comment: Ale_x, если не сложно, могли бы скинуть ссылки на материалы по данной теме?

Comment: можно спокойно использовать json_encode/json_decode, помоему самый простой вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у Вас имеется таблица table1 , в которой есть какие-то данные. В одном из столбцов есть вот эти значения - цифры (назовем numbers). 
Значит все numbers принадлежат к строке с возможным уникальным значением, к примеру id.
Тогда почему бы Вам не сделать еще одну таблицу table2 , где будут указаны эти значения без разделителей и id тех строк, которые в table1? 
Пример table2:

```
| id | IdInTable1 | Number |
  1        3          5
  2        6          1
  3        3          2
  4        3          4
```

Примерно так. Надеюсь это Вам подойдет.

Comment: хм, это принесет ускорение работы? 

получается, придется делать еще 1 запрос к этой таблице 2, чтобы получить весь список id, которые принадлежат к id таблицы 1.

Comment: Вот насчет этого я не уверен. Но думаю, что это лучше, чем потом разбирать массивы из этой строки с помощью explode'a . 
Если я заблуждаюсь, прошу сказать мне.

Comment: массив будет и в вашем случае - массив с id значений :) но у вас получается добавляется еще и 1 доп. запрос mysql

лучше конечно же протестировать, но мне именно ваш вариант не подходит

спасибо за то, что пытались мне помочь

Comment: хах, да) и у меня же массив)) надо же так загнаться)) Все, надо спать иногда) Спасибо.